# Integrals of simple functions that are equal almost everywhere.

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

I want to show that if $(X, M,\mu)$ is a measure space, $A_1, \ldots, A_n, B_1, \ldots, B_n \in M$, $\alpha_1,\ldots, \alpha_n \in \mathbb{R}$,

$$f=\sum_{j=1}^n \alpha_j \chi_{A_j}, \  \ g=\sum_{j=1}^n \alpha_j \chi_{B_j} $$

and $f=g$ almost everywhere, then $\int f d\mu=\int g d\mu$.

Can you help me?. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to assume that $f,h$ are integrable for the integral to make sense.

Answer (score 1):

Let $h = f-g$. Then $h\equiv 0$ a.e.

Define $A = \{x \in X : f(x) \neq g(x)\}$, i.e. the null-set, where $f$ and $g$ differ.

note, $|h| \leq 1_{A} \cdot \max\{\sup|f|, \sup|g|\}$.

$|h| \geq 0$ so we can try to calculate its integral, and it follows
$$\int |h|\,\mathrm{d}\mu \leq \int 1_{A} \cdot \max\{\sup|f|, \sup|g|\}\,  \mathrm{d} \mu= 0 \cdot \max\{\sup|f|, \sup|g|\} = 0$$

But $\int |h|\,\mathrm{d}\mu = \int h^+\,\mathrm{d}\mu + \int h^-\, \mathrm{d}\mu$, hence both of them are $0$.

$$\Rightarrow \int h\,\mathrm{d}\mu = \int h^+\,\mathrm{d}\mu - \int h^-\,  \mathrm{d}\mu = 0$$

From linearity of Lebesgue integral you, on the other hand, have
$$0 = \int h\,\mathrm{d}\mu = \int f\,\mathrm{d}\mu - \int g\,\mathrm{d}\mu$$

Comment: Why $|h|\leq 1_A\cdot \max\{\sup |f|, \sup |g|\}$? If $x\in A^c$ then Ok, but if $x\in A$ then $h(x)\neq 0$ and how to deduce this inequality?

Comment: You should have $|h| \le 1_A (\sup|f|+\sup|g|)$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $h=f-g$. Then $h =\sum_1 ^{n} \alpha_j \chi_{ C_j} $ where $C_j =A_j \Delta B_j$, the symmetric difference between $A_j$ and $B_j$. Assuming that $\alpha_j$ are distinct (which is what is usually done in defining integrals of simple function) we get $A_j =f^{-1} \{\alpha_j\}$ and $B_j =g^{-1} \{\alpha_j\}$ so $C_j \subset \{x ;f(x) \neq g(x)$. Hence $\mu (C_j)=0$ for each j which gives $\int h d\mu =0$ or $\int f d\mu =\int g d\mu$. The result is true even if $\alpha_j$'s are not distinct but the proof is messier.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that $f,g$ are integrable.

$h=f-g$ is simple, let $\beta_1,..,\beta_m$ be the non zero elements of the range of $h$, then
$h = \sum_k \beta_k 1_{h^{-1}(\{\beta_k\})}$.

We are given that $\mu (\cup_k h^{-1}(\{\beta_k\}) ) = 0$, hence each $h^{-1}(\{\beta_k\})$ mas measure zero.

Then $\int h d\mu = \sum_k \beta_k \mu (h^{-1}(\{\beta_k\})) = 0$.